# Why the bytes stream got by python socket.recvfrom is different from that crawled by WireShark?

Tags: python, sockets, recvfrom

I used the python socket to send a DNS query packet socket and listen to the response. Finally, I got a DNS response packet by the `socket.recvfrom(2048)` function as expected. But strangely, where I  compared the response packet with the packet crawled by Wireshark, I found there exists many difference.

The differences would be found as `3f` at the second picture.

The DNS response packet (The highlighted part) crawled by the Wireshark

[image]

The DNS response packet got by the `socket.recvfrom(2048)`

[image]

The Creating a Socket Part Codes:

```
    ipv = check_ip(dst)
    udp = socket.getprotobyname(Proto.UDP)
    if ipv == IPV.ERROR:
        return None
    elif ipv == IPV.IPV4:
        return socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, udp)
    elif ipv == IPV.IPV6:
        return socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, udp)
    else:
        return None
```

The Receiving a DNS response packet Part Codes:

```
    remained_time = 0
    while True:
        remained_time = self.timeout - timeit.default_timer() + sent_time
        readable = select.select([sock], [], [], remained_time)[0]
        if len(readable) == 0:
            return (-1, None)

        packet, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
```

Comment: Please post the text, not pictures of the text.  And tell us what part of the difference you found interesting.  They look about the same to me.

Comment: Do you mean the encoding is different?

Comment: No, I mean the byte stream itself. Compare the highlighted part with the bytes in the second picture . The differences would be found as `3f` in the second picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte `0x3F` is the ASCII `'?'` character. That commonly means the data is being treated as text and is passing through a charset conversion that doesn't support the bytes being converted.

Notice that `0x3F` is replacing only the bytes that are > `0x7F` (the last byte supported by ASCII). Non-ASCII bytes in the range of `0x80-0xFF` are subject to charset interpretation.

That makes sense, as you are using the version of `recvfrom()` that returns a `string`, so the received bytes need to be converted to Python's default `string` encoding.

Since you need raw bytes instead, use `recvfrom_into()` to fill a pre-allocated `bytearray`, eg:

```
packet = bytearray(4096)
remained_time = 0
while True:
    remained_time = self.timeout - timeit.default_timer() + sent_time
    readable = select.select([sock], [], [], remained_time)[0]
    if len(readable) == 0:
        return (-1, None)
    nbytes, addr = sock.recvfrom_into(packet)
```

Then you can use `packet` up to `nbytes` number of bytes as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There still seem to be some bytes which are lower than `0x7f` and translated into `0x3f`. For example, `shifen·com` in the first picture were translated into `shifen?·?+` in the second picture.

Comment: @TreeSimith that goes back to my point about "passing through a charset conversion that **doesn't support the bytes being converted**. Whatever charset was being used to generate the `string` clearly doesn't define any characters for bytes `0x6E` and `0x63` in the context they appeared. You will also notice that the `string` contains a `0x16` character that isn't in the source bytes. Your data is getting corrupted when converted to `string`, so get rid of the conversion.